# How to Distinguish between scanned PDF and native PDF in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

How to differentiate the scanned PDF and native PDF in Python?

Because both the documents having the extension with PDF only.

Is it possible to find whether the document is scanned PDF or native PDF by its properties?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I guess python libraries like pdfplumber, tesseract might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'mnot sure about the propeties, but if you zoom the page and curves still remain smooth - it's a Native PDF, if become uneven - it's scanned, because scanned PDF is no more than an image and don't have code that allows them to be edited.